# Can't load JSON data into Spinner Correctly

Tags: php, android, mysql, spinner

I have been trying for about 2 weeks to try and load an ArrayList to a spinner. I haven't had much luck as you can see from the commented out attempts in the below code. I left the comments in the code to show you I have tried literally hundreds of ways to do this. I can get the data to the spinner but it doesn't show up correctly. I tried to get the key : data from hashmap, load arraylist to spinner, get object from arraylist, and more. I am not very good with Java/Android but excellent in VB. I have been struggling pretty hard with Android. I would appreciate some help on this issue. Thank you in advance. Thanks again.

I tried uploading an image but I have a rep of 1. So, here is what I am getting:

```
THIS IS THE RESPONSE:
{"category":"Accessories"}
{"category":"Battery Packs"}
{"category":"Hunting Lights"}
{"category":"Other"}




 import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Shop extends Activity {
    //PHP to get catagories
    public static String url_to_send = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/load_catagories.php";
    //TAG to send to PHP to retrieve catagories
    private static final String TAG_CATAGORIES= "catagories";
    private static final String TAG_CATAGORY= "catagory";
    //Success tag
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    //Dialog
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    //JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray catagories = null;
    Spinner MySpinner;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> catagoryList;
    List<String> items;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop);
        MySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        catagoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    }
    String theCatagory;
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Shop.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Catagories. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_to_send, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Catagories: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    catagories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATAGORIES);

                    // looping through All Products
                    items = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < catagories.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = catagories.getJSONObject(i);
                        items.add(catagories.getString(i));

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        theCatagory = c.getString(TAG_CATAGORY);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_CATAGORY, theCatagory);
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        catagoryList.add(map);



                    }

                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                //  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, productsList,R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,TAG_NAME},new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                    //setListAdapter(adapter);
                    //ListAdapter adapter=new LazyAdapter(Shop.this, catagoryList);
                    //list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    //setListAdapter(adapter);

                    //String[] myData = {};
              //  myData = catagoryList.toArray(new String[catagoryList.size()]);
    // SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Shop.this, catagoryList,R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_CATAGORY},new int[] { theCatagory });
                    // MySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);



    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (Shop.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, catagoryList);       
                  //  MySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                    //ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
                //for(int i=0;i<catagories.length();i++)
                    //{

                        //try {
                        //list.add(catagories.getString(i));
                        //} catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        //  e.printStackTrace();
                        //}

                        //  }

        String [] anArrayOfStrings = new String[theCatagory.length()];
                            items.toArray(anArrayOfStrings);




                            ArrayAdapter<String>spinnerMenu = new ArrayAdapter<String(Shop.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,anArrayOfStrings);
        MySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerMenu);








                }

            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.shop, menu);
        return true;
    }

        }
```

Here is the All Catagories: LogCat

```
06-13 10:50:59.120: D/All Catagories:(5329): {"success":1,"catagories":[{"catagory":"Accessories"},{"catagory":"Battery Packs"},{"catagory":"Hunting Lights"}]}
```

Comment: have you got proper response.??

Comment: Can you post feedback from logCat on this line in your code: Log.d("All Catagories: ", json.toString()); ?

Comment: Added the LogCat output, identified the response. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is rather messy - probably after all the different attempts you made to get things working correctly - but I think the main problem areas are in `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()`.

After taking a minute to clean up your code, everything turned out to work fine, which means you were almost there. I mainly simplified the JSON parsing logic; i.e. you don't need a `Map`, and all you should do is simply add every category to a list which gets fed into the spinner adapter later on. See below for code snippet - if you find any variables you had before are now missing, that probably means I removed them because they aren't needed anymore.

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

/**
 * getting All products from url
 * */
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_to_send, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Catagories: ", json.toString());

        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

        if (success == 1) {
            // products found
            // Getting Array of Products
            JSONArray catagories = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CATAGORIES);

            // looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < catagories.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = catagories.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String category = c.getString(TAG_CATAGORY);

                items.add(category);
            }

        } else {
            // no products found
            // Launch Add New product Activity

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then `onPostExecute()`, from which I removed all the commented lines. Also, this method already gets run on the UI thread, so there's no need to post a `Runnable` on a `Handler`. It's okay to touch views directly here. The only other change was to supply `items` (which we populated with the categories in `doInBackground()`) to the adapter.

```
/**
 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
 * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
    pDialog.dismiss();

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerMenu = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Shop.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    MySpinner.setAdapter(spinnerMenu);
}
```

Comment: Lord. I was close. I do apologize for the messy code. I was pretty frustrated that no matter what I did I either got no result or the wrong result so I was trying to keep up with everything. Thanks for everything and your solution works perfect. Thanks a million MH.